# values obtained from parsing a json is not ordered

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

Im having the following json

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "value": {
    "shipment_master": {
      "1": "Order Placed",
      "2": "In Production",
      "3": "Quality Check In progress",
      "4": "Goods received for shipment",
      "5": "Stuffing in progress",
      "6": "Cargo Shipped"
    }
  }
}
```

Im parsing the above json and adding it to db as follows,

```
  NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
         NSArray *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"shipment_master"];

         for (NSDictionary *response in details) {
             NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

             // remove all rows

             [context performBlockAndWait:^{
                 // add new row(s)
                 NSManagedObject *master = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ShipmentMaster" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                 NSError *error;

                 // TODO: set values here (e.g. [pendingShipment setValue:...)
                 [master setValue:[details valueForKey:response] forKey:@"values"];

                 // save MOC
                 if ([context hasChanges]) {
                     (void)[context save:&error];
                 }
             }];
         }
```

The issue is that, when im fetching the data back again, the values are not in the same as order as they are received from the server.  I mean `orderplaced` comes after `in production`,`quality check in prorgress` comes after `inproduction`  so on and so forth....but when im fetching data, the data is unordered. Is it because the NSDictionary is fetches values in unordered way while parsing the json? or is there any other reason?

I tried changing `NSArray` to `NSDictionary` and `valueForKey` to `objectForKey` but still the same problem persists.

Following is my updated code,

```
NSString* pendingResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSData *jsonData = [pendingResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
             NSDictionary *valueDict = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"];
             NSDictionary *details = [valueDict objectForKey:@"shipment_master"];

             for (NSDictionary *response in details) {
                 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

                 // remove all rows

                 [context performBlockAndWait:^{
                     // add new row(s)
                     NSManagedObject *master = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ShipmentMaster" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                     NSError *error;

                     // TODO: set values here (e.g. [pendingShipment setValue:...)
                     [master setValue:[details objectForKey:response] forKey:@"values"];

                     // save MOC
                     if ([context hasChanges]) {
                         (void)[context save:&error];
                     }
                 }];
             }
```

Comment: the JSON contains only dictionaries (objects) and they have no order. where your code uses an array it shouldn't, because that doesn't match the underlying data...

Comment: may i know whats the replacement?

Comment: it's an `NSDictionary`. also where you use `valueForKey` should be `objectForKey`

Comment: I replaced `NSArray` with `NSDictionary` and `valueForKey` with `objectForKey` but still the same problem persists.

Comment: yes, that won't fix the problem, it's just things where you're confused about what the JSON is actually giving you. if you want an order you need to store something about the order as per the answer from @Russel, but you need to understand that the JSON is an unordered set of stuff even if the text prints in a specified order...

Answer (score 1):

if you want the data returned in a specific order, you need to specify that in your search predicate.  It looks like you're not storing the id, but you will need to store some form of index if the order is important.

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

Comment: i wish to save the order even while parsing the json and im using objective c for doing so